# Is there a way to make a fixed background images without lags?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, styling

I have tried many ways to make a background image as a fixed image. And I have seen websites where they have those fixed images without causing lags. But sadly I still haven't found the way to do it.

Here is a video of my current try:
https://streamable.com/hkk6d6

And my code:

```
import React from 'react'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    header: {
        position: "sticky",
        top: -63,
        zIndex: 101,
        height: "220px",
        '@media (max-width:600px)': {
            zIndex: 99,
        },
    },
    root: {
        backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
        flexWrap: "nowrap",
        flexDirection: "column",
        backgroundPosition: "50% 50%",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        display: "flex",
    }
}))
const Parallax = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.root} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.image})` }}>
            <div className={classes.header}>{props.header}</div>
            <div style={{ ...props.style, backgroundColor: props.theme.palette.contrast }}>{props.children}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export const ParallaxContainer = withTheme(Parallax);
```

Edit: The solution @Rounin suggested is working fine for me. I also found out that Image compression is not all. It's also important to decrease the size of high-resolution images.
To me it also helped, resizing the images to max 2000px per longer side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the key CSS property-value pair to create a parallax effect is:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Once you apply this property-value pair to an element (you can also do this using the shorthand `background` property, as in the example below), you're pretty much all set.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
height: 200vh;
margin-top: 180px;
}

.parallaxEffect {
width: 300px;
height: 180px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: rgb(127, 191, 255) url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/346529/pexels-photo-346529.jpeg') center / cover no-repeat fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallaxEffect"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. I tried using it, but it still causes lags if I have my 4 sections. Another problem I have with the shorthand attribute is, that the background-size property does not work. (I'm using Chrome)

Comment: After some more testing, I found out, that my image resolution was just to high to be able to be processed by my CPU properly. So I rescaled my image and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply be able to add an `img`-element with `position: fixed; z-index: -1` with a specified size to your HTML. That would place it behind all other content, with being fixed to the viewport.
To have parts of two or more images on your site, you could use the `clip-path`-property combined with JavaScript to clip the images at certain heights, perhaps using their parent-element's [`BoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) as bounds.
Combining it with a `window.onscroll`-event could help the performance, but I have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bg-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: "";//Your image here
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```
<div className={"bg-image"}>
    // Content
</div>
```